# using history command in the shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to get the command history inside a shell script.  It doesn't work unless I take out the #!/bin/bash

Any clues on how I can get it to work, or to achieve the same effect without removing #!/bin/bash?

Anyone know why it works to remove #!/bin/bash?

Comment: You could start by showing us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you take out the shebang line it's being run by your current shell.  Bash won't have any history to report unless you're using an "interactive" shell. Try changing your shebang line to:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

which will cause `bash` to start an interactive shell.

Comment: interesting.  My solution ended up being to run the script using the source command.  What's the difference between using #!/bin/bash -i and running script from source?

Comment: @MVTCplusplus When you source a script it runs in the context of the current shell. Any variables, functions, etc that are assigned/changed will be visible in the shell you run it (including any changes to the shell's history you might make with the history command). When you start a new interactive shell, those changes stay local to the shell running your script.  As to which one you want, it just depends on what your script is supposed to do.  But, sourcing the script is a reasonable solution as well.