# Does bash shell script leave its command history?

Tags: linux, bash

Does *bash* shell script leave the history of the commands it executed, such as `.bash_history`?

I'm curious about it.

Comment: If you set environment variable `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`, command with leading space (like `$  <space>command`) is not saved in the history.

Comment: @thatseeyou, Is it for interactive or for non-interective bash shells? Is it true for scripts? My bash don't allow to start sting in shell script with `$ ` - dollar-space special variable.

Comment: @osgx `$` is prompt. You can input only <space> + command.

Comment: And how your comment relates to the question of "shell scripts" which have no prompt and no history and no leading spaces (they are files, usually started with Shebang magical `#!` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html

> 9.1 Bash History Facilities
>
> When the `-o history` option to the set builtin is enabled (see The Set Builtin), the shell provides access to the command history, the list of *commands previously typed.*

To get current settings, use `set -o` command. In [interactive shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html) (with `-i` option of bash or in usual bashes from login or terminal) it prints `history on`. When used in scripts (`bash -c 'set -o'` or when you did `ssh machine bash` without tty allocation) it is unset: `history off`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html

> 6.3.3 Interactive Shell Behavior - When the shell is running interactively, it changes its behavior in several ways.
>
> 7. Command history (see Bash History Facilities) and history expansion (see History Interaction) are enabled by default. Bash will save the command history to the file named by $HISTFILE when a shell with history enabled exits.

History can be enabled in script with several commands: https://askubuntu.com/questions/546556/how-can-i-use-history-command-in-a-bash-script / https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script - set HISTFILE and (optionally) HISTTIMEFORMAT, enable with `set -o history` and then use `history` command.

Comment: Not sure about running bash scripts with `source script_name` command (or the same `. script_name`) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970058/#comment12738096_9970078 - it runs in the context of current bash and may have *some* history flags enabled (in fact it does not put commands into .bash_history as I remember). Also - what about subshells: `( some_command; )`?