Why can an invoked non-interactive bash shell read $HISTFILE but not from a bash script?
Note: this is a very specific question. Questions about other environment variables are unlikely to apply.
My $HISTFILE is set to /home/user/.bash_history and I would like to use it in a script file.
$HISTFILE is blank when used in a bash script.
Outside of the script file
echo $HISTFILE

returns
/home/user/.bash_history

and
bash -c "history"

does what you expect, it runs a non-interactive bash shell, runs history which returns nothing
so why does
bash -c "echo $HISTFILE"

currently return my history file path, but a bash script finds this variable empty?
I would expect it to also return empty.
Changing the shebang is not an option for my usecase
#!/bin/bash -i 

but does make the history command and $HISTFILE variables work in the script, but then records the script commands into history.

Currently I am hardcoding the path into the script, but I would love to understand the reason why this issue exists.

Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016084/does-bash-shell-script-leave-its-command-history

When you do
bash -c "echo $HISTFILE"

the variable is expanded by the interactive shell, not the non-interactive subshell, because variables are expanded inside double-quoted strings.
Change that to
bash -c 'echo "$HISTFILE"'

and you should get an empty result, because variables are not expanded inside single quotes, and the subshell receives $HISTFILE literally.
If you want the invoked shell to have access to $HISTFILE you can make it available in bash -cs environment by exporting it:
export HISTFILE
bash -c 'echo "$HISTFILE"'

or setting it again on the line where you call bash -c if you don't want to export it for some reason:
HISTFILE="$HISTFILE" bash -c 'echo "$HISTFILE"'


I'm actually surprised that HISTFILE isn't exported by default since it's all upper case.

All uppercase is used for both environment variables and internal shell parameters (e.g. IFS, PS1, etc.).
